Failed to build installable wheels for pocketsphinx
I am running Python 3.9.6 on Windows 11, I've installed swig and tried to install pocketsphinx but it keeps saying it failed to build wheels. I would really appreciate if someone could help guide me on how to fix this issue so I can install pocketsphinx.
Here's the error message I received:
Collecting sounddevice (from pocketsphinx)
  Using cached sounddevice-0.4.7-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: CFFI>=1.0 in d:\bing\coding\python_app\lib\site-packages (from sounddevice->pocketsphinx) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in d:\bing\coding\python_app\lib\site-packages (from CFFI>=1.0->sounddevice->pocketsphinx) (2.20)
Using cached sounddevice-0.4.7-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (200 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pocketsphinx
  Building wheel for pocketsphinx (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pocketsphinx (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
      2024-06-25 17:02:40,686 - scikit_build_core - INFO - RUN: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ncqwv4e2\normal\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake -E capabilities
      2024-06-25 17:02:40,715 - scikit_build_core - INFO - CMake version: 3.29.6
      *** scikit-build-core 0.9.6 using CMake 3.29.6 (wheel)
      2024-06-25 17:02:40,727 - scikit_build_core - INFO - Build directory: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq0xm2pmp\build
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2024-06-25 17:02:40,776 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
      2024-06-25 17:02:40,792 - scikit_build_core - INFO - RUN: C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ncqwv4e2\normal\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake -S. -BC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq0xm2pmp\build -CC:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq0xm2pmp\build\CMakeInit.txt
      loading initial cache file C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpq0xm2pmp\build\CMakeInit.txt
      -- Building for: NMake Makefiles
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
        Running

         'nmake' '-?'

        failed with:

         no such file or directory


      CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

      *** CMake configuration failed
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pocketsphinx)

